# MySQL Column 'FullName' cannot be null

Tags: java, mysql, exception, stored-procedures, jdbc

Currently having trouble fixing this MySQL Exception. I've checked several questions similar to mine and cant figure out why my FullName column isnt being accepted for input. I did a manual CALL Statement using MySQL Workbench and it worked perfectly, while trying to call it from Java code it doesn't like it.

Current Error:

```
Column 'FullName' cannot be null
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'FullName' cannot be null
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:931)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2985)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1631)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1723)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:3283)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1332)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1604)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1519)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1504)
at com.mysql.jdbc.CallableStatement.executeUpdate(CallableStatement.java:824)
at com.jpalenci.action.RequestAction.callInsertUserData(RequestAction.java:118)
at com.jpalenci.action.RequestAction.execute(RequestAction.java:49)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at ognl.OgnlRuntime.invokeMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:871)
at ognl.OgnlRuntime.callAppropriateMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:1294)
at ognl.ObjectMethodAccessor.callMethod(ObjectMethodAccessor.java:68)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.accessor.XWorkMethodAccessor.callMethodWithDebugInfo(XWorkMethodAccessor.java:117)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.accessor.XWorkMethodAccessor.callMethod(XWorkMethodAccessor.java:108)
at ognl.OgnlRuntime.callMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:1370)
at ognl.ASTMethod.getValueBody(ASTMethod.java:90)
at ognl.SimpleNode.evaluateGetValueBody(SimpleNode.java:212)
at ognl.SimpleNode.getValue(SimpleNode.java:258)
at ognl.Ognl.getValue(Ognl.java:494)
at ognl.Ognl.getValue(Ognl.java:458)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil$2.execute(OgnlUtil.java:315)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil.compileAndExecute(OgnlUtil.java:346)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil.getValue(OgnlUtil.java:313)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:430)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:290)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:251)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.DeprecationInterceptor.intercept(DeprecationInterceptor.java:41)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:168)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:76)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:229)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:229)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:191)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:73)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.DateTextFieldInterceptor.intercept(DateTextFieldInterceptor.java:125)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:91)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:253)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:140)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:193)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:189)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245)
at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:567)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:81)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Here is Current Method that I use for calling my Stored Procedure to Insert Data into my MySQL DB:

```
public static void callInsertUserData() throws SQLException{
    String insertUserData = "{CALL insertUserData(?,?,?,?,?,?)}";

    try{
        dbConn = getDBConn();
        callStmt = dbConn.prepareCall(insertUserData);

        callStmt.setString(1, in_FullName);
        callStmt.setString(2, in_PhoneNumber);
        callStmt.setString(3, in_EmailAddress);
        callStmt.setString(4, in_CheckOutDate);
        callStmt.setString(5, in_DeviceUsage);
        callStmt.setString(6, in_DeviceSelection);

        callStmt.executeUpdate();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (callStmt != null) {
            callStmt.close();
        }
    }
}
```

insertUserData Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `insertUserData`(
IN in_FullName VARCHAR(255),
IN in_PhoneNumber VARCHAR(255),
IN in_EmailAddress VARCHAR(255),
IN in_CheckOutDate VARCHAR(255),
IN in_DeviceUsage VARCHAR(255),
IN in_DeviceSelection VARCHAR(255)
)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO devices_requested (FullName, PhoneNumber, EmailAddress, CheckOutDate, DeviceUsage, DeviceSelection)
    VALUES (in_FullName, in_PhoneNumber, in_EmailAddress, in_CheckOutDate, in_DeviceUsage, in_DeviceSelection);
END
```

I have no clue what wrong with my Inserting Java code. Since this is a replica from a different project that I created last week and from a school assignment, they both worked. Could it be that I'm passing my information incorrectly? Or the ExecuteUpdate code that might be giving me issues?

Edit: Included Data Fields that I currently use.

```
//Data Fields That Come From User Inputted Data
private static String in_FullName;
private static String in_PhoneNumber;
private static String in_EmailAddress;
private static String in_CheckOutDate;
private static String in_DeviceUsage;
private static String in_DeviceSelection;
```

Comment: Obviously, in your code, `in_FullName` is null.

Comment: Can't be possible as I never specified `in_FullName` to be Null.

Comment: Before `callStmt.setString(1, in_FullName);` add `System.out.println(in_FullName);`. What's the output?

Comment: `null` Dunno why it appears as that.

Comment: Because `in_FullName` is set to `null`, OR, `in_FullName` is never set, so it takes a default value of `null`.

Comment: I have no idea then, Because I'm testing my other project that does the same thing and it works for that one. No clue how `in_FullName` is set to `null` by default.

Comment: `private static String in_FullName;` it's not initialized with any value, so it takes the default value of a `String`, which is `null`.

Comment: @RedPhanthom Why are you using a CALL procedure which only runs an `INSERT INTO` query instead of executing the `INSERT INTO` statement directly?

Comment: @Progman I was told to do that way from people I work with because of reason

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the issue that I was having, My getter/setters were coded incorrectly. I asked someone that does this type of Web Service and they were able to figure out the problem I was having.

I had my setters/getters with `static` since they were being made automatically by eclipse.Because of that, whenever I did a call for inserting data it wouldn't be able to get anything from my form that I was using with Struts.